# How to save image of superview into local mobile photo album

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am saving image to photo album.

drawImage Is imageview!

On top of **`UIImageView`** drawImage i am adding another `UIImageView stampImageView`;

```
  [drawImage addSubview:stampImageView];

 -(void)saveImage:(id)sender{

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(drawImage.image, nil, nil, nil);
    }
```

When i check the photo album after saving,  i can able to see the stampImage on that Which i added to drawImage.

Can any one let advice me about this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size); 
[self.drawImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

@ Thanks For to me, its working! for me when i used this above code.